# Why is it wrong to start the inductive step with p(k)?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, induction

I've never thought of this problem when I work with induction before. I am following [this video lecture](https://youtu.be/D3qVXZd-ONo?t=2939) and the instructor mentions that in inductive steps it is wrong to start with p(k) and try to construct p(k+1). Specifically, it is mentioned that when trying to prove that every non-empty finite set of real numbers contain its supremum, it is wrong to start inductive steps with a k-element set and add one element to it while the correct approach is to start with a set of k+1 elements and find a k-element set within it. Here is the [proof](https://app.box.com/v/su-math-131-fall2014/file/259286418300). Why is it wrong?

Comment: As a general rule that is an absurd thing to say. Of course you can often start with $p(k)$. Maybe in this particular proof there is some silliness about the empty set for the first value of $k$?

Comment: This is fairly subtle and semantic IMO. Your instructor wants to emphasise that you have to prove the most general form of $p(k + 1)$. The example with the square tilings illustrates this better, I think. The problem is that you're assuming every $k + 1$-set is formed by adding an element to a $k$-set, which you explicitly prove by starting with $p(k + 1)$ and using $p(k)$.

Comment: I think in generel it is 'wrong' to start a proof with an assumption. A proof normaly starts with what we have to show. In an indutive proof that is p(k+1), or more precice, under the assumption p(k) we deduce p(k+1). So we first study p(k+1) on its own, and then when it is needed use p(k) to conclude the proof. But I do not think that there are generel "rules" that forbid you to do so, or every proof has to be done like that. So I doubt there is a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

Induction always "starts" with $p(k)$. You assume $p(k)$ and try to prove $p(k + 1)$. I believe that you are confused about where to start the proof of $p(k + 1)$. *This* proof concerns arbitrary sets with $k + 1$ elements, so surely it must begin, "Let $A$ be a set with $k + 1$ elements; we will show that $A$ has a maximum."

You *could* start with a set containing $k$ elements, but eventually you must show that every set containing $k + 1$ elements is a set with $k$ elements plus an extra. These are just small semantics.

Explicitly, it is not *wrong* to start the proof of $p(k + 1)$ with a $k$-element set, it just may not be very helpful.